# How to loop an object and get specific value to push an array each

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got some case to loop an object which has multiple keys and get specific value and push to an array each, I hope anyone in this forum can help me thanks

```
[{
  "total_sms": 887,
  "total_submitted": 101,
  "total_in_queue": 696,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}, {
  "total_sms": 888,
  "total_submitted": 102,
  "total_in_queue": 697,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}]
```

expected

```
total_sms = [887,888]
total_submitted = [101,102]
and etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` to group by the keys of each object in your array. The keys of each object can be obtained from `Object.keys`.

Now for each key in the object if it is present then just add it to the array else create a new array and add that element:

```js
const data = [{
  "total_sms": 887,
  "total_submitted": 101,
  "total_in_queue": 696,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}, {
  "total_sms": 888,
  "total_submitted": 102,
  "total_in_queue": 697,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}];

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(ele);
    keys.forEach(key => acc[key] = acc[key] ? acc[key].concat(ele[key]) : [ele[key]]);
    return acc;
 }, {});
 console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick wasn't my question. Just wanted to give yo a quick complement before this question gets marked as a duplicate and removed.

Comment: @BigbossHighlight you can use `Object.values(yourObject)` to get the data elements out of the outer object and transform it into an array form given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let objs = [{
  "total_sms": 887,
  "total_submitted": 101,
  "total_in_queue": 696,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}, {
  "total_sms": 888,
  "total_submitted": 102,
  "total_in_queue": 697,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}];

let arrays = objs.reduce((arrays, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    arrays[key] = arrays[key] || [];
    arrays[key].push(value);
  });
  return arrays;
}, {});

console.log(arrays);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = [{
  "total_sms": 887,
  "total_submitted": 101,
  "total_in_queue": 696,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}, {
  "total_sms": 888,
  "total_submitted": 102,
  "total_in_queue": 697,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}
]

var obj = {

}

 temp.forEach(item => {
   Object.keys(item).map(key => {
     obj[key] = (obj[key]||[]).concat(item[key])
   })
 })

 console.log(obj)
```

Comment: It's not a dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single element data then `map()` will help you

```js
const array = [{
  total_sms: 887,
  total_submitted: 101,
  total_in_queue: 696,
  total_processed: 0,
  total_delivered: 0,
  total_failed: 0,
  date: '2019-08-06',
}, {
  total_sms: 888,
  total_submitted: 102,
  total_in_queue: 697,
  total_processed: 0,
  total_delivered: 0,
  total_failed: 0,
  date: '2019-08-06',
}];


const sms = array.map((m) => { return m.total_sms; });
console.log(sms);
```

If you want to all keys into an array then you can achieve it by only one `for` loop

```js
  const array = [{
    total_sms: 887,
    total_submitted: 101,
    total_in_queue: 696,
    total_processed: 0,
    total_delivered: 0,
    total_failed: 0,
    date: '2019-08-06',
  }, {
    total_sms: 888,
    total_submitted: 102,
    total_in_queue: 697,
    total_processed: 0,
    total_delivered: 0,
    total_failed: 0,
    date: '2019-08-06',
  }];
  
  const result = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    const element = array[i];
    Object.keys(element)
      .forEach((subElem) => {
        if (result[subElem]) {
          result[subElem].push(element[subElem]);
        } else {
          result[subElem] = [element[subElem]];
        }
      });
  }
  
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data.forEach(d => Object.keys(d).forEach(k=> r[k]=(r[k]||[]).concat(d[k]) ));
```

```js
let data = [{
  "total_sms": 887,
  "total_submitted": 101,
  "total_in_queue": 696,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}, {
  "total_sms": 888,
  "total_submitted": 102,
  "total_in_queue": 697,
  "total_processed": 0,
  "total_delivered": 0,
  "total_failed": 0,
  "date": "2019-08-06"
}];

let r={};

data.forEach(d => Object.keys(d).forEach(k=> r[k]=(r[k]||[]).concat(d[k]) ));

Object.keys(r).forEach(k=> this[k]=r[k] ); // save as global variables

console.log('total_sms =', total_sms);
console.log('total_submitted =', total_submitted);
console.log('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.reduce staring with an object having empty arrays and use `for .. in` inside it to fill that initial object from the current onw in the loop :

```js
var temp = [
  {
    total_sms: 887,
    total_submitted: 101,
    total_in_queue: 696,
    total_processed: 0,
    total_delivered: 0,
    total_failed: 0,
    date: "2019-08-06"
  },
  {
    total_sms: 888,
    total_submitted: 102,
    total_in_queue: 697,
    total_processed: 0,
    total_delivered: 0,
    total_failed: 0,
    date: "2019-08-06"
  }
];

const result = temp.reduce(
  (all, curr) => {
    for (let k in curr) {
      all[k].push(curr[k]);
    }
    return all;
  },
  {
    total_sms: [],
    total_submitted: [],
    total_in_queue: [],
    total_processed: [],
    total_delivered: [],
    total_failed: [],
    date: []
  }
);

console.log(result);
```